# Iterative GraphFrames AggregateMessages hitting memory limits

Tags: java, apache-spark, graphframes

I'm using GraphFrame's aggregateMessages capability to build a custom clustering algorithm. I tested this algorithm on a small sample dataset (~100 items) and verified that it works. But when I run this on my real dataset of 50k items, I am getting OOM errors after ~10 iterations. Interestingly, the first few iterations are processed in a couple mins and mem is the normal range. It's after iteration 6 that mem usage creeps to ~30GB and eventually bombs. I am running this on a 2 node cluster 16cores with 32GB.

Since this is an iterative algorithm and the fact that the mem after each iteration only increases, I wonder if I need to release memory somehow. I added the unpersist blocks at the end of the the loop but that hasnt helped.

Are there any other efficiencies I could use? Are there best practices around using GraphFrames in an iterative setting?

Another thing I've noticed is that on the spark UI of the executor page, the used "storage memory" for ~300MB, but the spark process is infact taking ~30GB. Not sure if this is a memory leak! [image]

```
while ( true ) {
    
    System.out.println("["+new Date()+"] Running " + i);
    Dataset<Row> lastRoutesDs = groups;
    Dataset<Row> groupUnwind = groups.withColumn("id", explode(col("routeItems")));

    GraphFrame gf = new GraphFrame(groupUnwind, edgesDs);
    
    Dataset<Row> lvl1 = gf.aggregateMessages()
            .sendToSrc(when(
                    callUDF("contains_in_array_str", AggregateMessages.dst().getField("routeItems"),
                            AggregateMessages.src().getField("id")).equalTo(false),
                    struct(AggregateMessages.dst().getField("routeItems").as("routeItems"),
                            AggregateMessages.dst().getField("routeScores").as("routeScores"),
                            AggregateMessages.dst().getField("grpId").as("grpId"),
                            AggregateMessages.dst().getField("grpScore").as("grpScore"),
                            AggregateMessages.edge().getField("score").as("edgeScore"))))
            .agg(collect_set(AggregateMessages.msg()).as("incomings"))
            .withColumn("inItem", explode(col("incomings")))
            .groupBy("id", "inItem.grpId")
            .agg(first("inItem.routeItems").as("routeItems"), first("inItem.routeScores").as("routeScores"),
                    first("inItem.grpScore").as("grpScore"), collect_list("inItem.edgeScore").as("inScores"))
            .groupBy("grpId")
            .agg(bestRouteAgg.apply(col("routeItems"), col("routeScores"), col("inScores"), col("grpScore"),
                    col("id"), col("grpScore")).as("best"))
            .withColumn("newScore", callUDF("calcRouteScores", expr("size(best.routeItems)+1"),
                    col("best.routeScores"), col("best.inScores")))
            .withColumn("edgeCount", expr("size(best.routeScores)"))
            .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());
    
    lvl1
            .filter("newScore > " + groupMaxScore)
            .withColumn("itr", lit(i))
            .select("grpId", "best.routeItems","best.routeScores", "best.grpScore", "edgeCount", "itr")
            .write()
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .json(workspaceDir + "clusters-rank-collect");

    if (lvl1.count() == 0) {
        System.out.println("****** End reached " + i);
        break;
    }

    
    Dataset<Row> newGroups = lvl1.filter("newScore <= " + groupMaxScore)
            .withColumn("routeItems_new",
                    callUDF("merge2Array", col("best.routeItems"), array(col("best.newNode"))))
            .withColumn("routeScores_new",
                    callUDF("merge2ArrayDouble", col("best.routeScores"), col("best.inScores")))
            .select(col("grpId"), col("routeItems_new").as("routeItems"),
                    col("routeScores_new").as("routeScores"), col("newScore").as("grpScore"));
    
    if (i > 0 && (i % 2) == 0) {
        newGroups = newGroups
                .checkpoint();
    }
    
    newGroups = newGroups
            .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
    System.out.println( newGroups.count() );
    
    groups.unpersist();
    lastRoutesDs.unpersist();
    groupUnwind.unpersist();
    lvl1.unpersist();
    
    groups = newGroups;
    
    i++;
}
```

Comment: 1) Can you print `sc.getPersistentRDDs()` at the end of each loop? 2) Try using `StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY()` for all persist operations?

Comment: Thanks mck, ill give it a shot in a bit. What should I do after i get the output from  "getPersistentRDDs"? Im guessing you want me to purge those RDDs?

Comment: Not really purging them all, I'm just curious whether there is any memory leak due to unexpectedly persisted dataframes. Some may be worth keeping because they will be reused in the next iteration.

Comment: You could use the method `AM.getCachedDataFrame(groups)` at the end of your loop. Unfortunately the scala documentation is currently broken but you might also get along with the Python version https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/api/python/graphframes.lib.html